# replace part of string php

Tags: php, regex

I need regular expression to replace `<` , `>` and `&` with `&lt;` , `&gt;` and `&amp;` 
but this characters I wanna replace just in `<body></body>` tags

example

Before replacing

```
<head> <><><>& </head> <body><><>&</body>
```

after replacing

```
<head> <><><>& </head> <body>&lt;&gt;&lt;&gt;&amp;</body>
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you really need is:

1. An xml parser to parse your string and get the `<body>` section. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/parsing-and-processing-html-xml) for more information;
2. [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for the result.

**Edit:** If you know exactly what the html looks like, you can of course also `explode` on `</head>` or `<body>` to split your input in two, but that would be highly dependant on the exact format of the input so I would not recommend it.

Comment: I need this because i have large xml file with this <, > and & in <body><body> and simplexml_load_file() can't read file
now i load file with file get content then I want to replace with preg_replace

Comment: @php12345 Perhaps something like XMLReader would work, see the question I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

To do this with a regex ti'll need to be done in a couple of steps:

1. Capture the body's inner string:

   regex: `(^.*?<body>)(.*)(<\/body>)$`

   [image]

   Matches:

   ```
   [0] => <head> <><><>& </head> <body><><>&</body>
   [1] => <head> <><><>& </head> <body>
   [2] => <><>&
   [3] => </body>
   ```
2. Replace each type of character separately inside matches[2]
3. Reconstruct the string

## PHP code example

```
$sourcestring="<head> <><><>& </head> <body><><>&</body>";
preg_match('/(^.*?<body>)(.*)(<\/body>)$/ims',$sourcestring,$matches);

$header=$Matches[1];
$body=$matches[2];
$footer=$Matches[3];

$body = preg_replace('/</ims','&lt;',$body);
$body = preg_replace('/>/ims','&gt;',$body);
$body = preg_replace('/&/ims','&amp;',$body);

$output = $header . $body . $footer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with some trick. Firstly I find text between body tags then I change it to html special chars and save it. After that I replace text between body tags with **[TO_BE_REPLACED]** and in the end I change the text to be replaced with text escaped by htmlspecialchars()

```
<?php
$str = '<head> <><><>& </head> <body><><>&</body>';
preg_match('/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/', $str, $match);
$special = htmlspecialchars($match[1]); // you can use html entities as well
$str = preg_replace('/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/','<body>[TO_BE_REPLACED]</body>',$str);
echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace('[TO_BE_REPLACED]', $special, $str)); //this one is only to show purpose
echo '<br>----<br>';
echo str_replace('[TO_BE_REPLACED]', $special, $str);
?>
```

[Check demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uc7-ypd)

Comment: This also changes double and single quotes to their respective character, which wasn't included in the OP.

Comment: @Denomales he can use array with str_replace if htmlspecialchars() is not need. He didn't mention that **ONLY** these characters are to be replaced.

Comment: True, however he was very explicit with which characters needed to be replaced.

Comment: @Denomales which looks exactly like html encoding... Your answer by the way uses 3 times preg_replace where you can use it one time and pass 2 arrays one as array of patterns and second array of replacements but the most simple way is to use str_replace also with arrays as arguments. What's sense of writing regex for "<".. I don't see any.